# JSTL: remove last item from array

Tags: java, jstl

Was wondering if it's possible to remove the last item from an array using JSTL?  Currently I'm using c:url to append parameters (from an array) to a hyperlink.  I want to be able to remove the last parameter as well...

Here is the code for the c:url to append parameters

```
 <c:url value="search" var="url">
    <c:param name="q" value="${q}"/>
    <c:forEach var="field" items="${fq}">
        <c:param name="fq" value="${field}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:url>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You can't manipulate arrays in JSTL. You can at highest set the last item to `null`, but that won't change the array's length.

In *your particular case* there's however another way: you can check if you're currently iterating over the last array item by checking [`LoopTagStatus#isLast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#isLast%28%29) and then just skip the item altogether in `<c:param>`

```html
<c:url value="search" var="url">
    <c:param name="q" value="${q}"/>
    <c:forEach var="field" items="${fq}" varStatus="loop">
        <c:if test="${not loop.last}">
            <c:param name="fq" value="${field}"/>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</c:url>
```

Note that I removed the `fn:length()` check because that's unnecessary. The `<c:forEach>` already won't iterate if there are no items.