# How to delete an Item from a List in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

We can delete items from list in Simple java class.

Now I want to delete an Item from a list which comes from controller.

I want to know that is there any replacement of **list.remove(int)** in JSTL ?

please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687374/jstl-remove-last-item-from-array

Comment: You can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687374/jstl-remove-last-item-from-array

Comment: both are different guys, one is array (size is fixed), and other is List(size is not fixed)

Comment: You shouldn't (I'd even write "you must not") manipulate the model in view, you should just display it. Use the controller to prepare the data to such form, that you don't need to delete them in view, and can just iterate and display them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the item in the **c:forEach** tag but you can use **c:if** tag to filter 'removedItem' from the options.

Check this. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSTL/JSTLModifyacollection.htm

And for example, if you have following scenerio:-

```
<select> 
  <option value="0">Select</option> 
  <c:forEach items="${list} var="list"> 
   <c:if test="${list.value != 'removedItem'}">   
    <option value="${list.value}">${list.displayText}</option>  
   </c:if>
  </c:forEach> 
</select>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is not helpful or the answer @Vikas, please understand the requirement.

Comment: @student-17 but the requirement is a misconception

Answer (score 0):

you can't remove exactly, but you can filter it out using `<c:if>`, as

```
<select> 
  <option value="0">Select</option> 
  <c:forEach items="${list} var="myList"> 
   <c:if test="${myList.value != 'something'}">  // if you know value then you can put in place of something, and filter it out. 
    <option value="${myList.value}">${myList.displayText}</option>  
   </c:if>
  </c:forEach> 
</select>
```

this is just an example, how you can remove it using `JSTL` , by filtering.
if you dont want dropdown, then you can remove `<select>` and `<option>` and start from `<c:forEach>`, and where we are storing data in option, replace it by something.

**explination of above code:**
as you can see, i loop the list, and where value is not `something` it add one `<option>` in select dropdown, in short, it removes from dropdown by filtering it.